# How to put Google Place Autocomplete list onto modal?

Tags: html, css, google-places-autocomplete

dialog is open by module on page.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <dialog id="dialog">
      <form method="dialog">
        <input type="text" id="google">
      </form>
    </dialog>

    <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg&callback=initMap&libraries=places"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in js file, I created the google autocomplete and focus on the input field in the dialog.

js code:

```
let autocomplete;

const addressDialog = document.querySelector("#dialog");
const addressGoogleField = document.querySelector("#google");

addressDialog.showModal();

function fillInAddress() {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
}

function initMap() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(addressGoogleField, {
        fields:["geometry"],
        types:["geocode"]
    });
    addressGoogleField.focus();

    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

results:
[Google Places Autocomplete Box is behind the modal dialog.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egtxj.png)

I want to put autocomplete box in front of the dialog. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a z-index issue. The Google Place Autocomplete box ("pac-container" css class) is appended at the end of the body element, and not within your modal dialog.
To ensure the autocomplete box is above your modal dialog div. You can try and update your css with :

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

The 10000 z-index is just a value high enough to be above the modal z-index.